# Save 3 different datasets into 3 different sheet under same excel file

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have 3 different dataset which i want to store in 3 different sheet under same excel file. I try as below. Is there any compact way for it to reduce programming complexity?

```
xbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('abcd.xlsx')
xsheet1 = xbook.add_worksheet('img_reshape')
xsheet2 = xbook.add_worksheet('column_sum')
xsheet3 = xbook.add_worksheet('row_sum')

for col,array in enumerate (dataset):
    for row,value in enumerate (array):
    xsheet1.write(row, col, value)
for col,array in enumerate (column_sum):
    for row,value in enumerate (array):
    xsheet2.write(row, col, value)
for col,array in enumerate (row_sum):
    for row,value in enumerate (array):
    xsheet3.write(row, col, value)
xbook.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) (python data analysis library) for this task.

Install it via `pip install pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
datasets = [dataset, column_sum, row_sum]
sheet_names = ['img_reshape', 'column_sum', 'row_sum']
excel_filename = 'abcd.xlsx'
with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_filename) as writer:
    for data, sheet in zip(datasets, sheet_names):
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, header=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way to do it. An example is provided in the xlsxwriter documentation (link [here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html)).
I've posted an example below that is fairly simple.  I've also added three sample dataframes so that this example can be reproduced by anyone. Also there are a slew of optional parameters that can be used with dataframe.to_excel that may interest you and these are outlined in Pandas Documentation. (link [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)).

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data_1': [10, 20, 30, ]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data_2': [20, 30, 40]})
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({'Data_3': [30, 40, 50]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('abcd.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df_1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='img_reshape')
df_2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='column_sum')
df_3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='row_sum')


writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd also recommend Pandas but if you want to do it with just XlsxWriter then you could do something like this:

```
import xlsxwriter

# Some sample data.
dataset = [[11, 12, 13, 14],
           [21, 22, 23, 24],
           [31, 32, 33, 34]]

column_sum = dataset
row_sum = dataset

xbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('abcd.xlsx')
xsheet1 = xbook.add_worksheet('img_reshape')
xsheet2 = xbook.add_worksheet('column_sum')
xsheet3 = xbook.add_worksheet('row_sum')

mappings = [(dataset, xsheet1),
            (column_sum, xsheet2),
            (row_sum, xsheet3)]

for dataset, worksheet in mappings:
    for row_num, row_data in enumerate(dataset):
        for col_num, cell_data in enumerate(row_data):
            worksheet.write(row_num, col_num, cell_data)

xbook.close()
```

Or for the inner loop you could do this:

```
# Write the data.
for dataset, worksheet in mappings:
    for row_num, row_data in enumerate(dataset):
        worksheet.write_row(row_num, 0, row_data)
```

Comment: is there pandas library is better than xlsxwriter ? if yes than i want to try it.